# How to make TD tag occupy entire space?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a single row with one single column occupy entire space of a row, and no a single column space:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>C1</th>
            <th>C2</th>
            <th>C3</th>
            <th>C4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>L1</td>
            <td>L2</td>
            <td>L3</td>
            <td>L4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ONE LINE</td> #THIS ONE I WANT TO OCCUPY SPACE OF 4 TDs 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I already tried it:

```
<td style="width:100%">ONE LINE</td>
```

and

```
<tr style="width:100%">
    <td>ONE LINE</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [colspan attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>C1</th>
            <th>C2</th>
            <th>C3</th>
            <th>C4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>L1</td>
            <td>L2</td>
            <td>L3</td>
            <td>L4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">ONE LINE</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I really didn't remeber this attr. I was trying to do it in css. Thanks